# OpenVPN routing issue

Tags: routing, openvpn

Building 1:
10.1.0.0    255.255.0.0

Building 2:
10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0

Buildings are connected by 1G metro ethernet.

I reside in building 1.

192.168.0.0 is firewalled from everyone.
OpenVPN is in 10.10.230.0
OpenVPN is in bridged mode so when I connect I get a 10.10.230.x address. 
192.168.0.0 is acccessible from anyone with a 10.10.x.x address.

I connect with OpenVPN using the "push redirect-gateway" option and everything works. However, I don't want this to be my DFG. I only want to use this tunnel for specific subnets so I use the "push route" option like this:

```
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0"
```

and turn off the "redirect-gateway"

I cannot access the 192.168.0.0 subnets.

Example:

```
C:\Users\me>tracert -d 192.168.2.6

Tracing route to 192.168.2.6 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *     10.10.230.181  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.


Route table: The routes are added. It looks like they are trying to be used by what the tracert shows.

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.1.150.1      10.1.150.62     10
          5.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link      5.227.46.162   9256
     5.227.46.162  255.255.255.255         On-link      5.227.46.162   9256
    5.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      5.227.46.162   9256
       10.1.150.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
      10.1.150.62  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
     10.1.150.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
      10.10.230.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     10.10.230.181    286
    10.10.230.181  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.181    286
    10.10.230.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.181    286
      10.10.231.0    255.255.255.0    10.10.230.179    10.10.230.181     30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0    10.10.230.179    10.10.230.181     30
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0    10.10.230.179    10.10.230.181     30
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.10.230.181    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      5.227.46.162   9256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.181    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      5.227.46.162   9256
===========================================================================
```

What am I missing? Again, using "redirect-gateway" I can access everything I need to access. What gives?

route table with redirect-gateway enabled

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.10.230.179    10.10.230.180     30
       10.1.150.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
      10.1.150.62  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
     10.1.150.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
      10.10.230.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     10.10.230.180    286
    10.10.230.179  255.255.255.255       10.1.150.1      10.1.150.62     10
    10.10.230.180  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.180    286
    10.10.230.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.180    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.10.230.180    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.150.62    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.230.180    286
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Please post what your rt looks like with redirect-gateways enabled. Also it is possible that your machine doesn't use its 10.10.230.X address as source address when contacting 192.168.2.0/23.

Answer (score 0):

when you have redirect-gateway enabled (looking at your rt's above), there is an entry for what appears to be the nexthop after your OpenVPN gateway:

```
10.10.230.179  255.255.255.255       10.1.150.1      10.1.150.62     10
```

Your first routing table doesn't have that, so it's possible that your client doesn't know how to route your OpenVPN traffic itself. Here is the routing table when I have OpenVPN enabled (no redirect gateway)

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.46.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.46.1    276
     192.168.46.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.46.1    276
   192.168.46.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.46.1    276
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.200.1   192.168.200.10     31
    192.168.192.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.192.1    276
    192.168.192.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.192.1    276
  192.168.192.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.192.1    276
    192.168.200.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.200.10    286
   192.168.200.10  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.200.10    286
  192.168.200.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.200.10    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.200.10    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.192.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.46.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.200.10    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.192.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.46.1    276
===========================================================================
```

I have added

```
push route "192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"
```

to my openvpn server config, so I can connect to another subnet on the other side of my openvpn server, that the openvpn server isn't on but is set up to route to. Also more info for the rt above:

My openvpn server IP is 192.168.200.1
My openvpn client IP is 192.168.200.10

So any traffic destined for 192.168.100.0 goes through the OpenVPN interface but is destined for 200.1, because my OpenVPN box has 2 eth connections and has iptables setup to route that traffic. So in your case (re-reading your question), I would check that there is a route on your OpenVPN server between the two interfaces to route the traffic from one interface to the other.