# OpenVPN doesn't tunnel

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I have a openvpn server which listens port 443 but it doesn't seem to tunnel my connections.

I run the client in a network that blocks FTP connections, it says it is connected to my server but in fact if i connect to a site via FTP, my connection is still blocked.

Shouldn't a VPN tunnel all my connections and let me access ports that are blocked in the network where i execute the client?

Comment: You have to configure the routing. http://superuser.com/questions/120069/routing-all-traffic-through-openvpn-tunnel?rq=1

Comment: @pjc50 How can i find my vpn interface address?

Comment: @Harlandraka you can find the address by going to network connections and double clicking the tap or tun network adapter.

Comment: @MDMoore313 and what address do i have to copy? ipv4 address? ipv4 subnet mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the link [that was posted in your question's comments](https://superuser.com/questions/120069/routing-all-traffic-through-openvpn-tunnel?rq=1) it will tell you how to configure your machine for this. The problem with that though, is that once you disconnect from the VPN you will not have internet access. The best way is for it to be implemented in the VPN server config files, [as I have outlined here](https://superuser.com/questions/437366/openvpn-routing-issue/532705#532705).

Comment: server settings are ok, it is working properly, but i'm not able to tunnel connections from client to server, i don't understand what is the address i have to look for in my client network connection properties

Comment: @Harlandraka If that's the case then be sure to run OpenVPN in elevated mode so that it can alter your routing table to add the appropriate routes.

Comment: Can you please tell me which address from connection properties i have to write instead of `a.b.c.d`?

Comment: @Harlandraka you're misunderstanding me. That ***will not*** give you a permanent solution.

Comment: Ok but i want to know what IP should i copy

Comment: @Harlandraka The IPv4 address.

Comment: It always results in `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` if i use the procedure shown in your first link

Comment: @Harlandraka Try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/437366/openvpn-routing-issue/532705#532705) on your server

Comment: How can i see my table?

Comment: @Harlandraka open a command prompt and type `route print`

Comment: My VPN is on 192.168.0.201 and in my server config file i already have `push route "192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"` Is it correct?